# Implement non-oAuth-based authentication in a Meteor app?

Tags: authentication, cookies, oauth, meteor

I’m trying to modify a Meteor app ([Telescope](https://github.com/TelescopeJS/Telescope)) to work with non-oauth-based authentication.

To be more specific, I want to use a cookie set by my larger web framework as a username/token based authentication mechanism. Specifically, I would like the client to pass the username and token from its cookie to the server. Then, the server will pass the username and token to my authentication server, which will verify whether the token is fresh and matches the username.

I’m confused on how to get this working with the Accounts framework. I thought it might be possible to extend the Accounts.validateLoginAttempt to perform the check, but there’s no real way to pass the cookie information to that method, is there?

Alternatively, I could create a new accounts-xxxx package, but all the other accounts packages seem to use oauth — will creating a non-oauth package be biting off more than I can chew?

Or is there a simpler solution I’m missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something simple that you may consider (over techniques) is the `loginToken`. You'll notice in your Meteor users collection there is a list under the `services` attribute called `resume`.

This contains pre-authenticated tokens the user can use to log in without asking for login details (its usually used for people who've already logged in on that device, similar to cookies).

The only difference is it uses localStorage over cookies and looks a bit like this:

```
Meteor.loginToken         => 4Cs_abcdEfghijklmn42cf4444445577889900120
Meteor.loginTokenExpires  => Wed Oct 08 2014 23:22:46 GMT
Meteor.userId             => abcDEBG4Abc45A5vg
```

If you are able to get (or create) the resume items from the user's resume you can use this to log in, perhaps using some other logic (e.g a link containing a token - like from an email) that sets the localStorage items above in your telescope app.

To set it its just `localStorage.setItem('Meteor.loginToken', '4cs_abcde....')` with the token that you've verified.

Just keep in mind you should verify the user with some kind of expirable token or something (maybe in the cookie like you mention) when you send them off to your telescope app since this does let people log in very easily.